# Get of IterationCumulativeFlowData of current iteration that belongs to a project

Tags: rest, rally

Is it possible to get 'IterationCumulativeFlowData' of **current** iteration that belongs to **specific** project name?

This gives me data for aberration by I must provide the iteration id:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/IterationCumulativeFlowData?&query=(IterationObjectID = 11111111)&fetch=true&pretty=true
```

I want to avoid that, by passing only the name of the project...

If it's not possible, how can I get the iteration of id of current iteration that belongs to specific project?

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/iteration?query=(Project.name = "xxxxx")&fetch=ObjectID&pretty=true
```

the above gives me all iterrations that belong to the project but I need current one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a special current iteration endpoint:

```
/iteration:current?project=/project/12345
```

You can't query it by project name, but you can specify the project by its object id.

Or, if you need it by project name then you can just do what you're doing in your second url above, but just also tack on additional filters for `((StartDate < today) AND (EndDate > today))`.

Comment: There is a problem using /iteration:current?project=/project/12345, somehow ,there are several versions of same iterration
`"VersionId": "5"` but what is returned from above query is always `versionid:1
the value of `PlannedVelocity` is different there, is there a way to return latest version of iteration?

Comment: Hmm, it shouldn't be possible to get old/stale versions of objects through the API.  I just tried to reproduce and couldn't.  It may be worth following up with Rally support if you continue to experience this issue.

Comment: If I access via iterationId I am getting the latest (I believe this is because each version has its own id)

Comment: Also I see now, that I must send workspace name as well, to get the correct project&iteration, any idea how to add it?

Answer (score 0):

To send workspace name and project follow below

Schema request by workspace:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/schema/v2.0/workspace//
Schema request by project (service discovers the workspace):

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/schema/v2.0/project//